# A script to change all tables and fields to the utf-8-bin collation in MYSQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql, utf-8, collation

Is there a `SQL` or `PHP` script that I can run that will change the default collation in all tables and fields in a database?

I can write one myself, but I think that this should be something that readily available at a site like this. If I can come up with one myself before somebody posts one, I will post it myself.

Comment: [Click here for script and follow the steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37049697/5737771)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Be careful! If you actually have utf stored as another encoding, you could have a real mess on your hands. Back up first. Then try some of the standard methods:

for instance
http://www.cesspit.net/drupal/node/898
http://www.hackszine.com/blog/archive/2007/05/mysql_database_migration_latin.html

I've had to resort to converting all text fields to binary, then back to varchar/text. This has saved my ass.

I had data is UTF8, stored as latin1. What I did:

Drop indexes.
Convert fields to binary.
Convert to utf8-general ci

If your on LAMP, don’t forget to add set NAMES command before interacting with the db, and make sure you set character encoding headers.

Answer (score 86):

Can be done in a single command (rather than 148 of PHP):

```
mysql --database=dbname -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" \
| awk '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}' \
| mysql --database=dbname &
```

You've got to love the commandline...
(You might need to employ the `--user` and `--password` options for `mysql`).

EDIT: to avoid foreign key problems, added `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` and `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Comment: great, it worked for me... some issue with character encodings with values on fields, luckily my db is small for now

Comment: @david It works great, but is it possible to log the query in command line or just notify when the batch process ends. currently when i run this, it starts a background process and i am not sure when it ends. I tried putting echo inside awk, but nothing works

Comment: When I use this command, I don't get any response. The prompt just "hangs". Not sure whether it actually executed, correctly or at all

Comment: @DavidWinterbottom for this answer you should have a statue erected in your honor in your home town.

Comment: You do need to be aware that this approach can cause problems. For one, after running this any latin1 columns that were TEXT will now be MEDIUMTEXT. As a result you could have silent data-loss/truncation. Refer to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets and http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/17/converting-character-sets/ for more detailed information.

Comment: this will error if you have views in your database. to exclude views replace `"SHOW TABLES"` with `"SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'"`. Requires MySQL 5.0.2 or greater.

Comment: The exact code for command line which i get answer: `mysql -u root -ppassword --database=dbname -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" | awk '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}' | mysql -u root -ppassword --database=dbname &`

Comment: In order to not return view I adapt this command in this way :
`mysql  -proot --database=dbname -B -N -e "SELECT  TABLE_NAME  FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schemaname'" | awk '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}'   | mysql  -proot --database=dbname`

Answer (score 41):

I think it's easy to do this in two steps runin PhpMyAdmin.
**Step 1:**

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', t.`TABLE_NAME`,
 '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') as stmt 
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` t
WHERE 1
AND t.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'database_name'
ORDER BY 1
```

**Step 2:**
This query will output a list of queries, one for each table. You have to copy the list of queries, and paste them to the command line or to PhpMyAdmin's SQL tab for the changes to be made.

Comment: please provide links to sites in English language or better, provide a full answer and only use links as reference!

Comment: Note that this query will NOT make any changes to your DB. It will output a list of queries -- one for each table.  So you have to COPY the list of queries, and PASTE them to the command line or to PHPMyAdmin's SQL tab for the changes to be made.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you, it is a very smart&crafty way to perform batch change of collations with only mysql or phpMyAdmin. It is very useful in redmine installation, where default collation is latin1 instead of utf8.

Answer (score 27):

OK, I wrote this up taking into account what was said in this thread. Thanks for the help, and I hope this script will help out others. I don't have any warranty for its use, so PLEASE BACKUP before running it. It *should* work with all databases; and it worked great on my own.

EDIT: Added vars at the top for which charset/collate to convert to.
EDIT2: Changes the database's and tables' default charset/collate

```
<?php

function MysqlError()
{
    if (mysql_errno())
    {
        echo "<b>Mysql Error: " . mysql_error() . "</b>\n";
    }
}

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "database";
$host = "localhost";

$target_charset = "utf8";
$target_collate = "utf8_general_ci";

echo "<pre>";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

$tabs = array();
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
MysqlError();
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) != null)
{
    $tabs[] = $row[0];
}

// now, fix tables
foreach ($tabs as $tab)
{
    $res = mysql_query("show index from {$tab}");
    MysqlError();
    $indicies = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) != null)
    {
        if ($row[2] != "PRIMARY")
        {
            $indicies[] = array("name" => $row[2], "unique" => !($row[1] == "1"), "col" => $row[4]);
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} DROP INDEX {$row[2]}");
            MysqlError();
            echo "Dropped index {$row[2]}. Unique: {$row[1]}\n";
        }
    }

    $res = mysql_query("DESCRIBE {$tab}");
    MysqlError();
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) != null)
    {
        $name = $row[0];
        $type = $row[1];
        $set = false;
        if (preg_match("/^varchar\((\d+)\)$/i", $type, $mat))
        {
            $size = $mat[1];
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} VARBINARY({$size})");
            MysqlError();
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} VARCHAR({$size}) CHARACTER SET {$target_charset}");
            MysqlError();
            $set = true;

            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }
        else if (!strcasecmp($type, "CHAR"))
        {
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} BINARY(1)");
            MysqlError();
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET {$target_charset}");
            MysqlError();
            $set = true;

            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }
        else if (!strcasecmp($type, "TINYTEXT"))
        {
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} TINYBLOB");
            MysqlError();
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET {$target_charset}");
            MysqlError();
            $set = true;

            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }
        else if (!strcasecmp($type, "MEDIUMTEXT"))
        {
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} MEDIUMBLOB");
            MysqlError();
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET {$target_charset}");
            MysqlError();
            $set = true;

            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }
        else if (!strcasecmp($type, "LONGTEXT"))
        {
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} LONGBLOB");
            MysqlError();
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET {$target_charset}");
            MysqlError();
            $set = true;

            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }
        else if (!strcasecmp($type, "TEXT"))
        {
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} BLOB");
            MysqlError();
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} TEXT CHARACTER SET {$target_charset}");
            MysqlError();
            $set = true;

            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }

        if ($set)
            mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab} MODIFY {$name} COLLATE {$target_collate}");
    }

    // re-build indicies..
    foreach ($indicies as $index)
    {
        if ($index["unique"])
        {
            mysql_query("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX {$index["name"]} ON {$tab} ({$index["col"]})");
            MysqlError();
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("CREATE INDEX {$index["name"]} ON {$tab} ({$index["col"]})");
            MysqlError();
        }

        echo "Created index {$index["name"]} on {$tab}. Unique: {$index["unique"]}\n";
    }

    // set default collate
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE {$tab}  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$target_charset} COLLATE {$target_collate}");
}

// set database charset
mysql_query("ALTER DATABASE {$db} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$target_charset} COLLATE {$target_collate}");

mysql_close($conn);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: Yup; so far so good. Ive been applying it one-by-one to my databases and so far no data loss.

Comment: Attention: By looking at the source code it seems to me that this script does not re-create multicolumn unique indexes, it just drops them.

Comment: Great Post! Has anyone altered this script to handle "multicolumn unique indexes"? Is so, please post or email me at gmail - jjwdesign. Thanks, Jeff

Comment: Only problem is that it drops all your multicolumn index. At least it shows a log letting you know what ones were dropped!

Comment: Very helpful starting point!  My answer updates this to handle multicolumn indices, binary collations, etc. and is cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 13):

This PHP snippet will change the collation on all tables in a db. (It's taken from [this site](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=682119).)

```
<?php
// your connection
mysql_connect("localhost","root","***");
mysql_select_db("db1");

// convert code
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $table)
    {
        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE " . $table . " CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");
        echo $key . " =&gt; " . $table . " CONVERTED<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: After I run it on my db, when I try to see the structure of my every table, I see: #126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_321_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using command line, based on @david's without the `awk`

```
for t in $(mysql --user=root --password=admin  --database=DBNAME -e "show tables";);do echo "Altering" $t;mysql --user=root --password=admin --database=DBNAME -e "ALTER TABLE $t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;";done
```

prettified

```
  for t in $(mysql --user=root --password=admin  --database=DBNAME -e "show tables";);
    do 
       echo "Altering" $t;
       mysql --user=root --password=admin --database=DBNAME -e "ALTER TABLE $t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;";
    done
```

Comment: You should add `--silent` to the first `mysql` command to avoid having an error for the first line, which is `Tables_in_xxx`. Also, escaping table names will avoid an error on tables using a reserved name (such as `Order`).

Answer (score 2):

A more complete version of the script above can be found here:

http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=1937

Please leave any feedback about this contribution here:http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1034214

Comment: Thanks Dustin! The Zen-Cart script (version) is exactly what I was looking for. It does handle the multi-field index/unique indexes properly. Awsome, it saves me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Example #1 of why link only answers are bad.

Answer (score 1):

Charset and collation are not the same thing. A collation is a set of rules about how to sort strings. A charset is a set of rules about how to represent characters. A collation depends on the charset.

Answer (score 1):

In scripts above all tables selected for convertation (with `SHOW TABLES`), but a more convenient and portable way to check the table collation before converting a table. This query does it:

```sql
SELECT table_name
     , table_collation 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my custom shell [collatedb](https://github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/blob/master/collatedb), it should work :

```
collatedb <username> <password> <database> <collation>
```

Example :

```
collatedb root 0000 myDatabase utf8_bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nlaq for the code, that got me started on the below solution.

I released a WordPress plugin without realising that WordPress doesn't set the collate automatically. So a lot of people using the plugin ended up with `latin1_swedish_ci` when it should have been `utf8_general_ci`.

Here's the code I added to the plugin to detect the `latin1_swedish_ci` collate and change it to `utf8_general_ci`.

Test this code before using it in your own plugin!

```
// list the names of your wordpress plugin database tables (without db prefix)
$tables_to_check = array(
    'social_message',
    'social_facebook',
    'social_facebook_message',
    'social_facebook_page',
    'social_google',
    'social_google_mesage',
    'social_twitter',
    'social_twitter_message',
);
// choose the collate to search for and replace:
$convert_fields_collate_from = 'latin1_swedish_ci';
$convert_fields_collate_to = 'utf8_general_ci';
$convert_tables_character_set_to = 'utf8';
$show_debug_messages = false;
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
foreach($tables_to_check as $table) {
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . $table;
    $indicies = $wpdb->get_results(  "SHOW INDEX FROM `$table`", ARRAY_A );
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `$table`" , ARRAY_A );
    foreach($results as $result){
        if($show_debug_messages)echo "Checking field ".$result['Field'] ." with collat: ".$result['Collation']."\n";
        if(isset($result['Field']) && $result['Field'] && isset($result['Collation']) && $result['Collation'] == $convert_fields_collate_from){
            if($show_debug_messages)echo "Table: $table - Converting field " .$result['Field'] ." - " .$result['Type']." - from $convert_fields_collate_from to $convert_fields_collate_to \n";
            // found a field to convert. check if there's an index on this field.
            // we have to remove index before converting field to binary.
            $is_there_an_index = false;
            foreach($indicies as $index){
                if ( isset($index['Column_name']) && $index['Column_name'] == $result['Field']){
                    // there's an index on this column! store it for adding later on.
                    $is_there_an_index = $index;
                    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "ALTER TABLE `%s` DROP INDEX %s", $table, $index['Key_name']) );
                    if($show_debug_messages)echo "Dropped index ".$index['Key_name']." before converting field.. \n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            $set = false;

            if ( preg_match( "/^varchar\((\d+)\)$/i", $result['Type'], $mat ) ) {
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` VARBINARY({$mat[1]})" );
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` VARCHAR({$mat[1]}) CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
                $set = true;
            } else if ( !strcasecmp( $result['Type'], "CHAR" ) ) {
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` BINARY(1)" );
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
                $set = true;
            } else if ( !strcasecmp( $result['Type'], "TINYTEXT" ) ) {
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` TINYBLOB" );
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
                $set = true;
            } else if ( !strcasecmp( $result['Type'], "MEDIUMTEXT" ) ) {
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` MEDIUMBLOB" );
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
                $set = true;
            } else if ( !strcasecmp( $result['Type'], "LONGTEXT" ) ) {
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` LONGBLOB" );
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
                $set = true;
            } else if ( !strcasecmp( $result['Type'], "TEXT" ) ) {
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` BLOB" );
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` MODIFY `{$result['Field']}` TEXT CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
                $set = true;
            }else{
                if($show_debug_messages)echo "Failed to change field - unsupported type: ".$result['Type']."\n";
            }
            if($set){
                if($show_debug_messages)echo "Altered field success! \n";
                $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `$table` MODIFY {$result['Field']} COLLATE $convert_fields_collate_to" );
            }
            if($is_there_an_index !== false){
                // add the index back.
                if ( !$is_there_an_index["Non_unique"] ) {
                    $wpdb->query( "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `{$is_there_an_index['Key_name']}` ON `{$table}` ({$is_there_an_index['Column_name']})", $is_there_an_index['Key_name'], $table, $is_there_an_index['Column_name'] );
                } else {
                    $wpdb->query( "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `{$is_there_an_index['Key_name']}` ON `{$table}` ({$is_there_an_index['Column_name']})", $is_there_an_index['Key_name'], $table, $is_there_an_index['Column_name'] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // set default collate
    $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE `{$table}` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$convert_tables_character_set_to} COLLATE {$convert_fields_collate_to}" );
    if($show_debug_messages)echo "Finished with table $table \n";
}
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (dumb? :) solution, using multi-select feature of Your IDE:

1. run "SHOW TABLES;" query and copy results column (table names).
2. multi-select beginnings and add "ALTER TABLE ".
3. multi-select endings and add "  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
4. run created queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is with phpmyadmin and some jQuery on console.

Go to table's structure and open chrome/firefox developer console (normally F12 on keyboard):

1. run this code to select all fields with incorrect charset and start modify:

   ```
   var elems = $('dfn'); var lastID = elems.length - 1;
   elems.each(function(i) {
       if ($(this).html() != 'utf8_general_ci') { 
          $('input:checkbox', $('td', $(this).parent().parent()).first()).attr('checked','checked');
       }       

       if (i == lastID) {
           $("button[name='submit_mult'][value='change']").click();
       }
   });
   ```
2. when page is loaded use this code on console to select correct encoding:

   ```
   $("select[name*='field_collation']" ).val('utf8_general_ci');
   ```
3. save
4. change the table's charset on "Collation" field on "Operation" tab

Tested on phpmyadmin 4.0 and 4.4, but I think work on all 4.x versions

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do this with just phpmyadmin if you don't have command line access or access to edit INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

First, listen to the advice of many of the other answers here - you can really screw things up here, so make a backup.  Now make a backup of your backup.  Also this is unlikely to work if your data is encoded differently than what you are changing it to.

Note that you will need to find the exact names of the offending schema and character encoding that you need to change from before starting.

1. Export the database as SQL; Make a copy; Open it in a text editor of your choice
2. Find and Replace the schema first, for example - find: **latin1_swedish_ci**, replace: **utf8_general_ci**
3. Find and Replace the character encodings if you need to, for example - find: **latin1**, replace: **utf8**
4. Create a new test database and upload your new SQL file into phpmyadmin

This is a super easy way to do it, but again, this will not change the encoding of your data, so it will only work in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I updated nlaq's answer to work with PHP7 and to correctly handle multicolumn indices, binary collated data (e.g. `latin1_bin`), etc., and cleaned up the code a bit.  This is the only code I found/tried that successfully migrated my database from latin1 to utf8.

```php
<?php

/////////// BEGIN CONFIG ////////////////////

$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = "";
$host = "";

$target_charset = "utf8";
$target_collation = "utf8_unicode_ci";
$target_bin_collation = "utf8_bin";

///////////  END CONFIG  ////////////////////

function MySQLSafeQuery($conn, $query) {
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_errno($conn)) {
        echo "<b>Mysql Error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "</b>\n";
        echo "<span>This query caused the above error: <i>" . $query . "</i></span>\n";
    }
    return $res;
}

function binary_typename($type) {
    $mysql_type_to_binary_type_map = array(
        "VARCHAR" => "VARBINARY",
        "CHAR" => "BINARY(1)",
        "TINYTEXT" => "TINYBLOB",
        "MEDIUMTEXT" => "MEDIUMBLOB",
        "LONGTEXT" => "LONGBLOB",
        "TEXT" => "BLOB"
    );

    $typename = "";
    if (preg_match("/^varchar\((\d+)\)$/i", $type, $mat))
        $typename = $mysql_type_to_binary_type_map["VARCHAR"] . "(" . (2*$mat[1]) . ")";
    else if (!strcasecmp($type, "CHAR"))
        $typename = $mysql_type_to_binary_type_map["CHAR"] . "(1)";
    else if (array_key_exists(strtoupper($type), $mysql_type_to_binary_type_map))
        $typename = $mysql_type_to_binary_type_map[strtoupper($type)];
    return $typename;
}

echo "<pre>";

// Connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);

// Get list of tables
$tabs = array();
$query = "SHOW TABLES";
$res = MySQLSafeQuery($conn, $query);
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) != null)
    $tabs[] = $row[0];

// Now fix tables
foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
    $res = MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "SHOW INDEX FROM `{$tab}`");
    $indicies = array();

    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) != null) {
        if ($row[2] != "PRIMARY") {
            $append = true;
            foreach ($indicies as $index) {
                if ($index["name"] == $row[2]) {
                    $index["col"][] = $row[4];
                    $append = false;
                }
            }
            if($append)
                $indicies[] = array("name" => $row[2], "unique" => !($row[1] == "1"), "col" => array($row[4]));
        }
    }

    foreach ($indicies as $index) {
        MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "ALTER TABLE `{$tab}` DROP INDEX `{$index["name"]}`");
        echo "Dropped index {$index["name"]}. Unique: {$index["unique"]}\n";
    }

    $res = MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `{$tab}`");
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) != null) {
        $name = $row[0];
        $type = $row[1];
        $current_collation = $row[2];
        $target_collation_bak = $target_collation;
        if(!strcasecmp($current_collation, "latin1_bin"))
            $target_collation = $target_bin_collation;
        $set = false;
        $binary_typename = binary_typename($type);
        if ($binary_typename != "") {
            MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "ALTER TABLE `{$tab}` MODIFY `{$name}` {$binary_typename}");
            MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "ALTER TABLE `{$tab}` MODIFY `{$name}` {$type} CHARACTER SET '{$target_charset}' COLLATE '{$target_collation}'");
            $set = true;
            echo "Altered field {$name} on {$tab} from type {$type}\n";
        }
        $target_collation = $target_collation_bak;
    }

    // Rebuild indicies
    foreach ($indicies as $index) {
         // Handle multi-column indices
         $joined_col_str = "";
         foreach ($index["col"] as $col)
             $joined_col_str = $joined_col_str . ", `" . $col . "`";
         $joined_col_str = substr($joined_col_str, 2);

         $query = "";
         if ($index["unique"])
             $query = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `{$index["name"]}` ON `{$tab}` ({$joined_col_str})";
         else
             $query = "CREATE INDEX `{$index["name"]}` ON `{$tab}` ({$joined_col_str})";
         MySQLSafeQuery($conn, $query);

        echo "Created index {$index["name"]} on {$tab}. Unique: {$index["unique"]}\n";
    }

    // Set default character set and collation for table
    MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "ALTER TABLE `{$tab}`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET '{$target_charset}' COLLATE '{$target_collation}'");
}

// Set default character set and collation for database
MySQLSafeQuery($conn, "ALTER DATABASE `{$db}` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET '{$target_charset}' COLLATE '{$target_collation}'");

mysqli_close($conn);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Windows Users

In addition to @davidwinterbottom answer,
windows users can use command below:

```
mysql.exe --database=[database] -u [user] -p[password] -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" \
| awk.exe '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}' \
| mysql.exe -u [user] -p[password] --database=[database] &
```

Replace [database], [user] and [password] placeholders with actual values.

**Git-bash** users can download this [bash script](https://gist.github.com/motammem/b57a93ae986d469b8dbb6b9264130a60) and run it easily.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's an extended version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545503/6226915 as a Yii2 ConsoleController class, which can also be used standalone: https://gist.github.com/cboulanger/d30c197235a53d9a2331f19a96d6e00d .

The script fixes a few bugs and adds support for fulltext indexes; also it deals with the regular index key length constraint of 3kb. It also converts all tables to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP [Laravel framework](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x):

1. Use migration: `php artisan make:migration update_character_set_utf8_m4`
2. Migration file logic

   ```
   $DBNAME = config('database.connections.mysql.database');
   $CHARACTER = 'utf8mb4';
   $COLLATE = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';

   echo "Altering DB $DBNAME\n";
   DB::unprepared("ALTER DATABASE $DBNAME CHARACTER SET $CHARACTER COLLATE $COLLATE;");

   $tables = DB::select("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{$DBNAME}'");
   foreach ($tables as $table) {
       echo "Altering $table->table_name\n";
       DB::unprepared("ALTER TABLE $table->table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $CHARACTER COLLATE $COLLATE;");
   }
   ```
3. `php artisan migrate`