# How to change collation of database, table, column?

Tags: mysql, collation

The database is `latin1_general_ci` now and I want to change collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

Is there any setting in PhpMyAdmin to change collation of database, table, column? Rather than changing one by one?

Comment: See this for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906585/how-to-change-the-default-collation-of-a-database/9531221#9531221

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You need to either convert each table individually:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

(this will convert the columns just as well), or export the database with `latin1` and import it back with `utf8mb4`.

Comment: But i want to change collation of columns. This is will change only the table collation..

Comment: `@rsensan`: `CONVERT` will change the collation of columns as well.

Comment: ALTER SCHEMA `database`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

Comment: @stormwild: this won't affect existing tables

Comment: two step process to update them all: http://georgepavlides.info/convert-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-to-utf8_general_ci/

Comment: My query:
ALTER TABLE `MYTABLE` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
[Please don't use utf8_general_ci anymore ;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE MYTABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for a sort order that correctly handles most languages

Comment: If you use phpMyAdmin -> Select your DB on the left tree > Sheet "Operations" (on top) > "Collation" (on bottom) : select the intended Collation and check "Change all tables collations" + "Change all tables columns collations" and press the button "Go". Done;

Comment: Yeah, I only want to change a few columns so this doesn't help me

Comment: @JonathanRys: down votes are for the incorrect answers. Is there any other problem with the answer, except that it does not help you?

Comment: @Quassnoi The title of the question implies that the OP wants three answers.  There is another answer down lower that I feel better answers the question.  I feel that should be the accepted answer so I downvoted this one and upvoted that one.

Comment: be aware that columns of large data amounts might not change though.

Answer (score 393):

I am contributing here, as the OP asked:

> **How to change collation of database, table, column?**

The selected answer just states it on table level.

---

Changing it database wide:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Changing it per table:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Good practice is to change it at table level as it'll change it for columns as well. Changing for specific column is for any specific case.

Changing collation for a specific column:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 
    COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: This one actually answers the question directly. I needed this, as my table-level changes were NOT updating the columns. I'll investigate that later; but this is the information that got me through the hard times. Thanks.

Comment: The best answer for this.

Comment: Yes, you need to specificities the column type. Here is a magic command to get all the types. Using multi-line editing you can generate the command to update all columns at once starting here: `SELECT table_schema
     , table_name
     , column_name
     , COLLATION_NAME
     , COLUMN_TYPE
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE collation_name != 'utf8_general_ci'
   AND table_schema not in ('information_schema','mysql',
                            'performance_schema','sys');`

Comment: For a single column you can simply do: ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name VARCHAR(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;

Comment: Do you always need the data type (e.g. `varchar(255)`? What about `TEXT`?

Comment: Does anybody know how can we detect / change collation of a user defined variable?

Comment: i changed the collate (alter table table.name character set = utf8mb4,  collate = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

but when i say show full columns from table, it still shows the columns as latin-swedish

Answer (score 69):

You can run a php script.

```
               <?php
                   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
                   if(!$con) { echo "Cannot connect to the database ";die();}
                   mysql_select_db('dbname');
                   $result=mysql_query('show tables');
                   while($tables = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
                             mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $value CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
                       }}
                   echo "The collation of your database has been successfully changed!";
                ?>
```

Answer (score 50):

To change collation for tables individually you can use,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

To set default collation for the whole database,

```
ALTER DATABASE  `databasename` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

or else,

Goto **PhpMyAdmin->Operations->Collation.**

There you an find the select box which contains all the exsiting collations. So that here you can change your collation. So here after database table will follows this collation while you are creating new column . No need of select collation while creating new columns.

Answer (score 28):

The following query will generate ALTER queries that change the collation for all appropriate columns in all tables to a certain type (utf8_general_ci in my example below).

```
SELECT concat
        (
            'ALTER TABLE ', 
                t1.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
                '.', 
                t1.table_name, 
                ' MODIFY ', 
                t1.column_name, 
                ' ', 
                t1.data_type, 
                '(' , 
                    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
                ')', 
                ' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'
        )
from 
    information_schema.columns t1
where 
    t1.TABLE_SCHEMA like 'you_db_name_goes_here' AND
    t1.COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL AND
    t1.COLLATION_NAME NOT IN ('utf8_general_ci');
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer the most. Not everyone has PHP magically somewhere. Some of use use other languages with MySQL. This was easy to run in MySQL Workbench, copy the rows and paste. I just did the extra step to run the above for `information_schema.tables` and the code in concat `ALTER TABLE 'schema'.'table' CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 , COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin ;`

Comment: This bugs out on (medium/long)text column types, which have to be cleaned up manually

Comment: You can use SCHEMA() function, instead of 'you_db_name_goes_here'

Comment: And you're losing NULLable and DEFAULT options.

Answer (score 18):

Generates query to update each table and column of each table.
I have used this to some of my projects before and was able to solved most of my COLLATION problems. (especially on JOINS)

To use, just export results to delimited text (probably new line '\n')

**EACH TABLE**

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, 
              '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;') 
       AS 'USE `DATABASE_NAME`;' 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_NAME' 
       AND TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'BASE TABLE'
```

**EACH COLUMN**

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '` MODIFY COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME,'` ', 
              DATA_TYPE, IF(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL 
       OR DATA_TYPE LIKE 'longtext', '', CONCAT('(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
                                         ')') 
       ), ' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ', IF(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES', 'DEFAULT NULL;', 'NOT NULL;')) AS 'USE `DATABASE_NAME`;' 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DATABASE_NAME' 
       AND (SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_TYPE 
            FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = 
                   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA 
                   AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = 
                       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME 
            LIMIT  1) LIKE 'BASE TABLE' 
       AND DATA_TYPE IN ( 'char', 'varchar' ) /* include other types if necessary */
```

Comment: Worked for me. You can use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` if this is causing constraint errors, just turn it back on with `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;` after the database updates.

Comment: Thank you, this was an extremely helpful answer.

Comment: What a great and clever piece of work.

Comment: Bear in mind that the "each column" script does not consider the "not null" constraint and the generated lines will change previously non null columns to nullable.

Comment: "Each column" script has been updated for "not null" columns. Credits to @digitalbreed and RB Projects

Answer (score 11):

If you run phpMyAdmin >> select database >> select table >> go to "Operations" tab >> in "Table options" section >> you can pick Collation from the drop down list >> and once you press {Go} at the top of the screen you will see a message:

> Your SQL query has been executed successfully

and a script

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

But it will NOT change the collations of existing columns.
To do so you can use this script (this one also came from phpMyAdmin)

```
ALTER TABLE  `tableName` CHANGE  `Name`  `Name` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL
```

Comment: Newer phpMyAdmin versions offer a checkbox to change the collation for all tables and all table columns.

Answer (score 9):

you can set default collation at several levels:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html

1) client
2) server default
3) database default
4) table default
5) column

Answer (score 8):

Just run this SQL to convert all database tables at once. Change your COLLATION and databaseName to what you need.

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME," COLLATE utf8_general_ci;") AS    ExecuteTheString
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="databaseName"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

Answer (score 8):

Better variant to generate SQL script by SQL request. It will not ruin defaults/nulls.

```
SELECT concat
    (
        'ALTER TABLE ', 
            t1.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
            '.', 
            t1.table_name, 
            ' MODIFY ', 
            t1.column_name, 
            ' ', 
            t1.column_type,
            ' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci',
            if(t1.is_nullable='YES', ' NULL', ' NOT NULL'),
            if(t1.column_default is not null, concat(' DEFAULT \'', t1.column_default, '\''), ''),
            ';'
    )
from 
    information_schema.columns t1
where 
    t1.TABLE_SCHEMA like 'your_table_here' AND
    t1.COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL AND
    t1.COLLATION_NAME NOT IN ('utf8_general_ci');
```

Comment: Changing only table collation is not applied for columns. Only this scripts help with my case.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the CHARSET and COLLATION of all your tables through PHP script as follows. I like the answer of hkasera but the problem with it is that the query runs twice on each table. This code is almost the same except using MySqli instead of mysql and prevention of double querying. If I could vote up, I would have voted hkasera's answer up.

```
<?php
$conn1=new MySQLi("localhost","user","password","database");
if($conn1->connect_errno){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
$res=$conn1->query("show tables") or die($conn1->error);
while($tables=$res->fetch_array()){
    $conn1->query("ALTER TABLE $tables[0] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci") or die($conn1->error);
}
echo "The collation of your database has been successfully changed!";

$res->free();
$conn1->close();

?>
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, after upgrading to Zabbix 5. Just to say that I changed the **Charset** and **Collation** like this:  `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin`.

Answer (score 4):

I read it here, that you need to convert each table manually, it is not true. Here is a solution how to do it with a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS changeCollation$$

-- character_set parameter could be 'utf8'
-- or 'latin1' or any other valid character set
CREATE PROCEDURE changeCollation(IN character_set VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_table_name varchar(255) DEFAULT "";
DECLARE v_message varchar(4000) DEFAULT "No records";

-- This will create a cursor that selects each table,
-- where the character set is not the one
-- that is defined in the parameter

DECLARE alter_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
AND COLLATION_NAME NOT LIKE CONCAT(character_set, '_%');

-- This handler will set the value v_finished to 1
-- if there are no more rows

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

OPEN alter_cursor;

-- Start a loop to fetch each rows from the cursor
get_table: LOOP

-- Fetch the table names one by one
FETCH alter_cursor INTO v_table_name;

-- If there is no more record, then we have to skip
-- the commands inside the loop
IF v_finished = 1 THEN
LEAVE get_table;
END IF;

IF v_table_name != '' THEN

IF v_message = 'No records' THEN
SET v_message = '';
END IF;

-- This technic makes the trick, it prepares a statement
-- that is based on the v_table_name parameter and it means
-- that this one is different by each iteration inside the loop

SET @s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',v_table_name,
' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ', character_set);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET v_message = CONCAT('The table ', v_table_name ,
' was changed to the default collation of ', character_set,
'.\n', v_message);

SET v_table_name = '';

END IF;
-- Close the loop and the cursor
END LOOP get_table;
CLOSE alter_cursor;

-- Returns information about the altered tables or 'No records'
SELECT v_message;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

After the procedure is created call it simply:

```
CALL changeCollation('utf8');
```

For more details read this [blog](http://blog.marit.ag/2015/06/09/mysql-change-collation-for-all-tables-in-your-database/).

Comment: This saved my Friday. Bookmarked for future reference

Answer (score 4):

You can simple add this code to script file

```
//Database Connection
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'your_database_name';
$db_user =  'your_database_user_name';
$db_pass = 'your_database_user_password';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_pass);

if(!$con) { echo "Cannot connect to the database ";die();}

  mysql_select_db($db_name);

  $result=mysql_query('show tables');

  while($tables = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $value CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
  }
}

echo "The collation of your database has been successfully changed!";
```

Answer (score 4):

I was surprised to learn, and so I had to come back here and report, that the excellent and well maintained Interconnect/it SAFE SEARCH AND REPLACE ON DATABASE script has some options for converting tables to utf8 / unicode, and even to convert to innodb.  It's a script commonly used to migrate a database driven website (Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, etc) from one domain to another.

[image: interconnect script buttons]

- https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB
- https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 3):

I used the following shell script. It takes database name as a parameter and converts all tables to another charset and collation (given by another parameters or default value defined in the script).

```
#!/bin/bash

# mycollate.sh <database> [<charset> <collation>]
# changes MySQL/MariaDB charset and collation for one database - all tables and
# all columns in all tables

DB="$1"
CHARSET="$2"
COLL="$3"

[ -n "$DB" ] || exit 1
[ -n "$CHARSET" ] || CHARSET="utf8mb4"
[ -n "$COLL" ] || COLL="utf8mb4_general_ci"

echo $DB
echo "ALTER DATABASE $DB CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql

echo "USE $DB; SHOW TABLES;" | mysql -s | (
    while read TABLE; do
        echo $DB.$TABLE
        echo "ALTER TABLE $TABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql $DB
    done
)
```

Comment: i needed to add parameters to every mysql command: -usqluser -ppassword with proper sql user and password to access the database. Otherwise worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 3):

My solution is a combination of @Dzintars and @Quassnoi Answer.

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME," CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ;") AS    ExecuteTheString
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="<your-database>"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

By using `CONVERT TO`, this generates a scripts, which converts all the Tables of `<your-database>` to your requested encoding. This also changes the encoding of **every column**!

Comment: This is certainly the best answer! I just wanted to paste it by myself but it's here already! Note, it seems like you don't really need to add "COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;" part at then like in some of the answers it seems to be extra!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to update the default charset on a schema:

```
 ALTER SCHEMA MYSCHEMA DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick way - export to SQL file, use search and replace to change the text you need to change. Create new database, import the data and then rename the old database and the new one to the old name.

Answer (score 0):

**To change the collation of all fields in all tables of a database at once:**

I was just adding another loop for the fields within the tables to the solution via Php before mentioned. This has helped, all fields in the tables are also converted.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pw');
if(!$con) { echo "Cannot connect to the database ";die();}
mysql_select_db('database_name');
$result=mysql_query('show tables');
while($tables = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

foreach ($tables as $key => $table) {                   // for each table

    $sql = "ALTER TABLE $table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
    echo "\n".$sql;
    mysql_query($sql);

    $sql = "show fields in ".$table." where type like 'varchar%' or type like 'char%' or type='text' or type='mediumtext';";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql);
    while( $rw2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2) ){            // for each field in table

        $sql = "ALTER TABLE `".$table."` CHANGE `".$rw2['Field']."` `".$rw2['Field']."` ".$rw2['Type']." CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;";
        echo "\n".$sql;
        mysql_query($sql);

    } 


}
}
echo "The collation of your database has been successfully changed!";

?>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, after changing the charset for database/table/column, you might need to actually convert the existing data (if you see, for example, something like "Ù…Ø·Ù„ÙˆØ¨ ØªÙˆØ±ÙŠØ¯ Ø¬Ù") with something like this:

```
update country set name = convert(cast(convert(name using latin1) as binary) using utf8), cn_flag = convert(cast(convert(cn_flag using latin1) as binary) using utf8), and so on..
```

While for converting database, tables and fields, I would suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509747/2090822) answer from this thread which would generate a big set of queries that you will just copy at paste, here I couldn't find an automatic solution yet.
Also be warned, if you will convert the same field twice you will get unrecoverable question marks: "???". You will also get this question marks if you will convert data before converting fields/tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the collates of all databases, tables and columns in a cluster with many bases.

I used a script running on php 8.1 and mysql 8.0

```
function changeCollate() {
    $databases = $this->fetchQueryToArray("SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'nova_%'")->rows;
    foreach ($databases as $value) {
        $db = $value['Database (nova_%)'];
        $this->LOG("-- banco de dados --- " . $db);
        $this->exeQuery("ALTER DATABASE `$db` COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;");
        $this->exeQuery("use $db");
        $tables = $this->fetchQueryToArray("SHOW tables")->rows;
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $tb_name = $table["Tables_in_$db"];
            $this->exeQuery("ALTER TABLE `$tb_name` COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;");
            $QUERY = "ALTER TABLE `$db`.`$tb_name`\n";
            $columns = $this->fetchQueryToArray("SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM $tb_name WHERE Type LIKE 'varchar%' OR Type = 'text' OR Type like 'enum%' OR Type = 'longtext' OR Type = 'mediumtext'")->rows;
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $QUERY .= "CHANGE `{$column['Field']}` `{$column['Field']}` {$column['Type']} COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'";
                $QUERY .= ($column['Null'] == 'YES') ?  " NULL" : " NOT NULL";
                if ($column['Default']) $QUERY .= " DEFAULT '{$column['Default']}'";
                if ($column['Comment']) $QUERY .= " COMMENT '{$column['Comment']}'";
                $QUERY .= ",\n";
            }
            if ($QUERY == "ALTER TABLE `$db`.`$tb_name`\n") continue;
            $QUERY = substr($QUERY, 0, -2) . ";\n\n";
            $this->exeQuery($QUERY);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` version.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
# Converts database, table and column collations.
# Only executes needed changes.
# Outputs SQL commands that are being run.
# Does not ask questions! Have a backup!
# @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294117/how-to-change-collation-of-database-table-column

# saner programming env: these switches turn some bugs into errors
set -o errexit -o pipefail -o noclobber -o nounset

### settings:
# mysqlCmd: Use `mysql --host --user ...` as needed in your environment.
# Depending on what you want to do, you can use `ssh mysql`
# or `mysql` wrappers like `ddev mysql`, `docker-compose exec -T db mysql` etc., too.
mysqlCmd="mysql"
db=db
charset=utf8mb4
collation=utf8mb4_general_ci

### script:
cmds="$($mysqlCmd --skip-column-names <<<"
    -- DB
    SELECT
        -- some debug output: what has it been before?
        CONCAT (
            'SELECT \"Old: ',
            DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME,
            ', ',
            DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME,
            '\";'
        ),
        CONCAT (
            'ALTER DATABASE \`',
            SCHEMA_NAME,
            '\` CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;\n'
        )
    FROM
        information_schema.SCHEMATA
    WHERE
            SCHEMA_NAME like '$db'
        AND (
                DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME != '$charset'
            OR
                DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME != '$collation'
        )
    ;

    -- tables
    SELECT
        -- some debug output: what has it been before?
        CONCAT (
            'SELECT \"Old: ',
            TABLE_COLLATION,
            '\";'
        ),
        CONCAT (
            'ALTER TABLE \`',
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            '\`.\`',
            TABLE_NAME,
            '\` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;\n'
        )
    FROM
        \`information_schema\`.TABLES
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA like '$db' AND
        TABLE_COLLATION IS NOT NULL AND
        TABLE_COLLATION NOT IN ('$collation')
    ;


    -- columns
    SELECT
        -- some debug output: what has it been before?
        CONCAT (
            'SELECT \"Old: ',
            CHARACTER_SET_NAME,
            ', ',
            COLLATION_NAME,
            '\";'
        ),
        CONCAT (
            'ALTER TABLE \`',
            TABLE_SCHEMA,
            '\`.\`',
            TABLE_NAME,
            '\` MODIFY \`',
            COLUMN_NAME,
            '\` ',
            COLUMN_TYPE,
            ' CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;\n'
        )
    FROM
        \`information_schema\`.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA like '$db' AND
        COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL AND
        COLLATION_NAME NOT IN ('$collation')
    ;
")"

# output SQL commands
#echo -e "$cmds"

# execute
$mysqlCmd -v --skip-column-names <<<"$cmds"
```

Tested with MariaDB 10.4 - 10.6, MySQL 5.7

Answer (score -1):

I've just written a bash script to find all tables in a given database and covert them (and its columns).

Script is available here: https://github.com/Juddling/mysql-charset