# MySQL : ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have read **Database system concepts**, 6th edition, *Silberschatz*. I'm going to implement the university database system shown in chapter 2 on OS X on MySQL. But I have a trouble with creating the table `course`. the table `department` looks like

```
mysql> select * from department
    -> ;
+------------+----------+-----------+
| dept_name  | building | budget    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| Biology    | Watson   |  90000.00 |
| Comp. Sci. | Taylor   | 100000.00 |
| Elec. Eng. | Taylor   |  85000.00 |
| Finance    | Painter  | 120000.00 |
| History    | Painter  |  50000.00 |
| Music      | Packard  |  80000.00 |
| Physics    | Watson   |  70000.00 |
+------------+----------+-----------+

mysql> show columns from department
    -> ;
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_name | varchar(20)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| building  | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| budget    | decimal(12,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Creating the table `course` causes the following error.

```
mysql> create table course
    -> (course_id varchar(7),
    -> title varchar (50),
    -> dept_name varchar(20),
    -> credits numeric(2,0),
    -> primary key(course_id),
    -> foreign key (dept_name) references department);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

after searching google for foreign key constraint, I have just learned that the word 'foreign key constraint' indicates that data from foreign key column in the table `course` must exist in primary key column in the table `department`. But I should have met this error when inserting data.

If not, why does author make me execute that SQL statement?

If I really execute erroneous SQL statement, Does I have to designate `dept_name` in course table as foreign key after inserting some data?

**EDIT** : typing `set foreign_key_checks=0` into `mysql>` does not fix the error.

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2013-09-21 16:02:20 132cbe000 Error in foreign key constraint of table university/course:
foreign key (dept_name) references department):
Syntax error close to:
)
mysql> set foreign_key_checks=0
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> create table course
    -> (course_id varchar(7),
    -> title varchar(50),
    -> dept_name varchar(20),
    -> credits numeric(2,0),
    -> primary key(course_id),
    -> foreign key (dept_name) references department);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535110/242520

Comment: all `dept_name` in both table is varchar(15). where Does I have to type `set foreign_key_checks=0`?

Comment: typing `set foreign_key_checks=0` into `mysql>` does not fix the error.

Comment: What does `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` say?

Comment: says, 2013-09-21 16:02:20 132cbe000 Error in foreign key constraint of table university/course:
foreign key (dept_name) references department):
Syntax error close to:
)

Comment: Maybe you want `foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)`

Comment: Might I trouble you to provide `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` again, after changing to `departments(dept_name)`?

Comment: It works with `foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)`. I don't know why author made me execute `foreign key (dept_name) references department)`.

Comment: `foreign key (dept_name) references department` is ANSI standard SQL. Maybe the author didn't work with MySQL but with a more standard compliant DBMS.

Comment: if you check syntext in mysql doc, `index_col_name` before and after `REFERENCES tbl_name` is required.

Comment: Yes, It's my fault. I believed that author give me super SQL working on any database system.

Comment: @inherithandle: the author **did** give you correct SQL, it's just MySQL that doesn't comply with the ANSI standard in this regard (and many others)

Comment: To get a detailed error: run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The syntax of `FOREIGN KEY` for `CREATE TABLE` is structured as follows:

```
FOREIGN KEY (index_col_name)
        REFERENCES table_name (index_col_name,...)
```

So your MySQL DDL should be:

```
 create table course (
        course_id varchar(7),
        title varchar(50),
        dept_name varchar(20),
        credits numeric(2 , 0 ),
        primary key (course_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (dept_name)
            REFERENCES department (dept_name)
    );
```

Also, in the `department` table `dept_name` should be `VARCHAR(20)`

More information can be found in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I would be happy for you to explain what is that statements in detail. I have never seen the statemnt `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: `CONSTRAINT link_dept_course` giving a symbol to this relationship. and it is optional. If the clause is not given, or a symbol is not included following the CONSTRAINT keyword, a name for the constraint is created automatically. FYI :  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: The constraint part is optional, but the list of PK columns is not. So the `references department` vs. `references department  (dept_name)` indeed fixes it. I didn't know that MySQL doesn't support the "short hand" notation (as defined by the SQL standard)

Comment: I also discovered that if your table has multiple primary key columns the foreign key constraint will not be able to add.

Answer (score 102):

When you get this vague error message, you can find out the more specific error by running

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

The most common reasons are that when creating a foreign key, both the referenced field and the foreign key field need to match:

- **Engine** should be the same *e.g. InnoDB*
- **Datatype** should be the same, and with same length.
  *e.g. VARCHAR(20) or INT(10) UNSIGNED*
- **Collation** should be the same. *e.g. utf8*
- **Unique** - Foreign key should refer to field that is unique *(usually private)* in the reference table.

Another cause of this error is:
*You have defined a SET NULL condition though some of the columns are defined as NOT NULL.*

Comment: I just got tripped up because one field was `UNSIGNED` while the other was not, so just edited your answer to include that. Hope that's OK.

Comment: @SimonEast thx for pointing me in the right direction had the same Issue :)

Comment: This should have been the Accepted answer as it's going to be most helpful to people who find this page looking for solutions to their problem

Comment: Got the same problem: if `ON DELETE SET NULL` is used all columns must seem to be nullable. [Here is another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33735266/57091).

Comment: I got this error because the referenced tables were not marked with `ENGINE=InnoDB` - which was also not obvious from the ***very badly*** formatted output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

Comment: Vaibhav your edit to this answer should be it's own answer

Comment: A more verbose output would be SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G as it 'pivots' the output by 90 degrees and you can more easily scroll the output.

Answer (score 24):

Maybe your `dept_name` columns have different charsets.

You could try to alter one or both of them:

```
ALTER TABLE department MODIFY dept_name VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE course MODIFY dept_name VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: That one was tricky. I had one table using explicitly UTF8, not the other. When migrating to a server not using UTF8 as the default, the working schema stopped working. This saved me!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, in my case the primary key was utf8_bin and the "wannabe-foreign" was utf8_general_ci. This saved me too!

Answer (score 6):

```
foreign key (dept_name) references department
```

This syntax is not valid for MySQL. It should instead be:

```
foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
```

[MySQL requires `dept_name` to be used twice](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Once to define the foreign column, and once to define the primary column.

> ## 13.1.17.2. Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints
>
> ... [the] essential syntax for a foreign key constraint definition in a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statement looks like this:
>
> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>     [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>     REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name, ...)
>     [ON DELETE reference_option]
>     [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>     RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
> ```

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to get this error if the foreign key is not a primary key within its own table.

I did an ALTER TABLE and accidentally removed the primary key status of a column, and got this error.

Answer (score 5):

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

It is also worth noting that you get this error when the *type* of the column that is a foreign key in another able doesn't explicitly match the column in the correct table.

For example:

```
alter table schoolPersons
         add index FKEF5AB5E532C8FBFA (student_id),
         add constraint FKEF5AB5E532C8FBFA
         foreign key (student_id)
         references student (id);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

This was because the `student_id` field was defined as:

```
mysql> desc schoolPersons;
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| student_id         | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

while the `id` field in the `student` table was defined as:

```
mysql> desc persons;
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------+
| Field        | Type                 | Null | Key | Default           | Extra           |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment  |
```

The `bigint(20)` (generated from Java `long` by hibernate) is not compatible with `int(10) unsigned` (Java `int`).

Answer (score 3):

> I don't meet the problem as you. But I get the same ERROR Message. So I mark it down here for others' convience.

Check the charset of two table if the column type is `char` or `varchar`. I use a `charset=gbk`, but I create a new table whose default `charset=utf8`. So the charset is not the same.

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

To solve it is to use the same charset. For example `utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add 'unsigned' for the FOREIGN constraint

```
`FK` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that this error can also happen if the target table or column you're using in the REFERENCES portion simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me

```
set @@foreign_key_checks=0;
ALTER TABLE  `table1` ADD CONSTRAINT `table1_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`coloumn`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when I tried to import (in MysqlWorkbench) from a PhpAdminMySQL export. After verifying I had disabled the unique keys and foreign keys with:

```
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

I still get the same error (MySQL : ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint). The error occurred on this create statement.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `f1_pool`;
CREATE TABLE `f1_pool` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional',
 `ownerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `lastmodified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

No foreign key or unique index, so what is wrong here?
Finally (after 90 minutes puzzling) I decided to restart MySQL and do the import again with one modification: I dropped all tables before doing the import.
And there was no error, all functioned, tables and views restored.
So my advice, if all looks ok, first try to restart MySQL!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the engine is different between the parent table and the child table. Making the engines equal is working

The problem:
parent table 'engine' => 'MyISAM',
child table 'engine' => 'innoDB',

Correção:
parent table 'engine' => 'MyISAM',
child table 'engine' => 'MyISAM',

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30281310)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone stating this explicitly and I had this same error message and my problem was that I was trying to add a foreign key to a TEMPORARY table. Which is disallowed as [noted in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table. The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine. **They must not be TEMPORARY tables.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue as well. Not sure why this is working but it indeed works: 
Try add ENGINE INNODB after your create query.

```
mysql> create table course
-> (course_id varchar(7),
-> title varchar (50),
-> dept_name varchar(20),
-> credits numeric(2,0),
-> primary key(course_id),
-> foreign key (dept_name) references department) ENGINE INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is not directly linked precisely to your situation, it may help further readers to note that you can get exactly the same error output when you type `show engine innodb mstatus` if you do not respect the order of creating the database tables; meaning you must not add a foreign constraint referencing a table that does not exist yet. The reference table must exist prior to the table which points to it.

This is also true when the table creation order is respected but not the columns involved in the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

In my case charset, datatype every thing was correct. After investigation I found that in parent table there was no index on foreign key column. Once added problem got solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be aware it can be several different things.

In my case it was the table/field collation:

- FK target: `CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`
- FK source field: `CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Because related tables should have the same config about CHARSET and ENGINE.
Execute:

```
show table status from <DATABASE_NAME>;
```

See Engine and Collation about your table.
When you create put after ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Answer (score -1):

```
CONSTRAINT vendor_tbfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (V_CODE) REFERENCES vendor (V_CODE) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

this is how it could be... look at the referencing column part. (V_code)