# mysql unable to add foreign key: error 1215 (hy000)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting error 1215 (hy000): cannot add foreign key constraint then I run the following .sql file.  The code below is also not creating the documents table, probably because it fails to create its foreign keys.  Can anyone show me how to fix the code below so it will create the documents table including its foreign keys without throwing errors:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS petclinic;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON petclinic.* TO pc@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pc';

USE petclinic;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS types (
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(80),
  INDEX(name)
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documenttypes (
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(80),
  INDEX(name)
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS owners (
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(30),
  last_name VARCHAR(30),
  address VARCHAR(255),
  city VARCHAR(80),
  telephone VARCHAR(20),
  INDEX(last_name)
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pets (
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  birth_date DATE,
  type_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  owner_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  INDEX(name),
  FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES types(id)
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documents (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id int(4) NOT NULL,
  type_id INT(4), 
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  filename varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  content mediumblob NOT NULL, 
  content_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES owners(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES documenttypes(id)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

I tried the advice [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930084/mysql-error-1215-hy000-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint), but none of those suggestions work with this code.  Can someone show me something that does work with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key columns have to be the exact same data type as the original columns.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS documents (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  type_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  filename varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  content mediumblob NOT NULL, 
  content_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES owners(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES documenttypes(id)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

Added `UNSIGNED` to `client_id` and `UNSIGNED NOT NULL` to `type_id` (the NOT NULL part in is not mandatory though)

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bde8c)</kbd>

Comment: Though, the `NOT NULL` shouldn't be needed to match type for `type_id`. Just the `INT(4) UNSIGNED`.

Comment: That is true. I'll add a note in my answer.