# MySQL ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have looked everywhere about this error and seen plenty of examples and still i cant figure out whats wrong with my script. Im sorry if this is a common issue but searching about it hasnt helped me so far. Here goes the script:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ventas;
USE ventas

CREATE TABLE TIENDAS (
nif varchar(10) not null,
nombre varchar(20),
direccion varchar(20),
poblacion varchar(20),
provincia varchar(20) check (provincia = upper(provincia)),
codpostal int(5),
PRIMARY KEY (nif)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE FABRICANTES (
cod_fabricante int(3) not null,
nombre varchar(15) check (nombre = upper(nombre)),
pais varchar(15) check (pais = upper(pais)),
PRIMARY KEY (cod_fabricante)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE ARTICULOS (
articulo varchar(20) not null,
cod_fabricante int(3) not null,
peso int(3) unsigned not null CHECK (peso > 0),
categoria varchar(10) not null,
precio_venta int(4) unsigned CHECK (precio_venta > 0),
precio_costo int(4) unsigned CHECK (precio_costo > 0),
existencias int(5),
PRIMARY KEY (articulo,cod_fabricante,peso,categoria),
FOREIGN KEY (cod_fabricante) references FABRICANTES (cod_fabricante)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE PEDIDOS (
nif varchar(10) not null,
articulo varchar(20) not null,
cod_fabricante int(3) not null,
peso int(3) unsigned not null CHECK (peso > 0),
categoria varchar(10) not null,
fecha_pedido date not null,
unidades_pedidas int(4),
PRIMARY KEY (nif,articulo,cod_fabricante,peso,categoria,fecha_pedido),
FOREIGN KEY (cod_fabricante) references FABRICANTES (cod_fabricante),
FOREIGN KEY (articulo) references ARTICULOS (articulo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (cod_fabricante) references ARTICULOS (cod_fabricante) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (peso) references ARTICULOS (peso) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (categoria) references ARTICULOS (categoria) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (nif) references TIENDAS (nif)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Please make sure that CHARACTER SET and COLLATION is same for VARCHAR fields.

Comment: Depending on the version of MySQL you may need to create an index on pedidos columns which you are using as FK

Comment: A foreign key can only reference a primary or unique column.

Comment: Please check this link.let me inform `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930084/mysql-error-1215-hy000-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint`

Comment: Also mysql ingnores check constraints.

Comment: To get a detailed error: run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your ARTICULOS table, you have multiple columns as primary key .i.e. articulo,cod_fabricante,peso,categoria. In the PEDIDOS table, you are referring a foreign key articulo to ARTUCULOS table's articulo column. Which I think is wrong.

By the SQL standard, a foreign key must reference either the primary key or a unique key of the parent table. If the primary key has multiple columns, the foreign key must have the same number and order of columns

Comment: THANKS A LOT!! That was the issue. Never would have figured it out without your help. When I changed the PEDIDOS table this way: FOREIGN KEY (articulo,cod_fabricante,peso,categoria) references ARTICULOS (articulo,cod_fabricante,peso,categoria) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 instead of using split Foreign keys, it worked wonders.