# ERROR : [HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want add foreign key like this :

```
ALTER TABLE prepayment_log
ADD CONSTRAINT prepayment_log_modify_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (modify_id) REFERENCES member (user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

but SQL workbench output error code [HY000][1215]

I can sure that member (user_id) is varchar(50), also prepayment_log (modify_id) is varchar(50).

I don't know what is the problem. pls...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL : ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930084/mysql-error-1215-hy000-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: I find the ans, because of user_id using unicode utf-8 defalt, and I using unicode utf-8 ci for modify_id