# MySQL Workbench - Error ERROR 1215 (HY000) with foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have the following two tables:

[image]

[image]

I need to add UT as foreign key for Id_UT, but the entries in "referenced column" disappear.

[image]

It seems to me that all the constraints for the key values are satisfied (datatype, size, uniqueness). What can be wrong here?. Thank you.

Here a minimum working example:

```html
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.17, for Win32 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: newschema
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.7.17

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `catalogo_reperti`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalogo_reperti`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `catalogo_reperti` (
  `UT` varchar(45) COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Id_Reperto` varchar(45) COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Documentazione` text COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Reperto`,`UT`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_Reperto_UNIQUE` (`Id_Reperto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `catalogo_unita_topografiche`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalogo_unita_topografiche`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `catalogo_unita_topografiche` (
  `Id_UT` varchar(45) COLLATE utf16_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_UT`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_UT_UNIQUE` (`Id_UT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Are you trying to create a foreign key and get an error message, or does the foreign key disappear, or something else?

Comment: The foreign key simply disappears from "referenced column". If  I use the alter table command, it returns a generic 1215 error.

Comment: @Discipulos take a look at the following link. It might helps you [MySQL : ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930084/mysql-error-1215-hy000-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: I have already checked the question, but all constraints here seem correct and the alter table command returns an error.

Comment: Could be that Id_UT contains values that don't exist in the other table. The FK constraint would then be violated already when it is created.

Comment: BTW, there is no code in your question that creates an FK. Could you please add the code that causes the error?

Comment: I have added the structure which causes the error.

Comment: Maybe something went wrong there? The question doesn't contain any code that creates an FK.

Comment: There is the SQL create table  generating the structure  which in Mysql workbench gives me the mentioned error.

Comment: Your question still does not include the code that generates the foreign key. But it looks like you need an index on `UT` (as the first column).

Comment: Because I am using the tool provided by Workbench (Figure 3).

Comment: What kind of index?

Comment: You need any index on `catalogo_reperti(UT)` (or one that starts with that column) for your foreign key to work. In general, you should check all your indexes: having both a unique index and the primary key on `Id_UT` is redundant (a primary key is already unique), and a unique key on `Id_Reperto`, when `(Id_Reperto,UT)` is your primary key might indicate that the primary key is incorrectly chosen (as just `Id_Reperto` would already make a primary key, so check if `Id_Reperto` is really unique or if `UT` should really be part of the primary key).

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the declaration of Charset/collation (instead of leaving the default ones, which anyway are set to be the same) allows the program to declare the foreign key.