# Django: "Cannot add foreign key constraint" when creating test tables before running unit tests

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing, foreign-keys

I am trying to run unit tests that I've written for my Django project, but testing fails at the database creation stage. I have a single database "test", one of which as a foreign key relationship with another. I run the following:

```
python3 manage.py test --settings myapp.settings_test
```

And see the following output:

```
Creating test database for alias 'test'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_test'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_test', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'test'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

I've seen many answers such as this: [Django MySQL error when creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561458/django-mysql-error-when-creating-tables).

Such answers show that, in general, this error is caused by adding a table that has a foreign key field before adding the table that the foreign key referencing. However, I have not found many helpful answers on how to address this in a testing scenario.

Other things I have tried:

- I've tried to run tests in a Django shell so that I can then use "django.db.connection" to show the raw MySQL commands Django is running, but I can't seem to figure out how to run the tests in the Django shell.
- I've tried to run tests without migrations (https://pypi.org/project/django-test-without-migrations/) but that seems to have no effect.
- In my test settings file, I added the MIGRATION_MODULES variable to address the app "badapp" that has the foreign key field:

  MIGRATION_MODULES = {
      'badapp': None
  }

  but this made no difference as well.

I would like to know:

1.) How can I verify that this error is caused by adding tables in the incorrect order?

2.) How can I force tables to be added in a specific order when running tests?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [reddit version of the question](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/8dofs3/cannot_add_foreign_key_constraint_when_creating/), you have `'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"` set in the database options. What happens when you remove that? And what's your default storage engine (I'm assuming InnoDB but want to check)?

Comment: The default storage engine is indeed InnoDB. When I remove the options parameter from the database definition, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you specify a custom `MIGRATION_MODULES` entry that points to a path that does not contain a `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a problem with the migrations, i run

```
python manage.py test --verbosity=3
```

to check the execution trace, after verifying the trace I could see that the tables of my models were not being created, so i execute

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and the test can run perfectly It should be noted that my models do not have foreign keys, so the error was quite strange.