# Running django auth migrations doesn't create tables in db

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have been using django for many years but have not seen such issue before.

I am working on an old/legacy project. And I am originally facing [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561458/django-mysql-error-when-creating-tables). So as the solution suggest, I run `auth` migrations first,

```
$python manage.py migrate auth
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: auth
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
```

But when I check my mysql database, only `django_migrations` table gets created. I don't see `auth_user`, `auth_group`, `auth_permissions`, etc.

```
$python manage.py showmigrations auth
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length

mysql> show tables;
django_migrations
```

I am using `Python3.6` and `Django==1.11.5`. My `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like this,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'djcelery',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'djangosaml2',

    # ... more apps from my project
]
```

What could be wrong? Has anyone come across such issue.

Comment: Have a look at those two commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate just to check if the migrations are ok

Comment: I just updated my post.

Comment: @Hussain does the `showmigrations` command returns `[X]` ? or `[ ]` ?

Comment: It shows [X] @JPG

Comment: Is it possible to log-in to Django Admin?

Comment: No. "Table 'mydb.auth_user' doesn't exist")

Comment: Are you sure you have your database settings configured corretly? Use `python manage.py dbshell` and then run `SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: Same result. Don't see `auth_` tables. I only see `django_migrations` table. And when I `select * from django_migrations` it shows all `auth` and `contenttypes` migrations applied. So weird.

Comment: Same here. Because it looks like Django has not migrated all tables, I cannot login into admin dashboard. It prints out `relation "auth_user" does not exist`