# SQL #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints

I've got this code to create an SQL table, however I'm facing a #1215 error.

```
CREATE TABLE ‘Categorie’ (
‘catID’ int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
‘naam’ varchar(20) NOT NULL,
‘prioriteit’ int(2) NOT NULL,
‘subCatVan’ int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (‘catID’),
CONSTRAINT ‘subCatVan’ FOREIGN KEY (‘subCatVan’) REFERENCES Categorie

(‘catID’) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: The syntax looks correct and could not be replicated http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b68e7

Comment: What does the documentation say for error #1215?

Comment: There are wrong ticks in your statement. all must be backticks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: The DBMS might fall over the fact you're using the same name for both the constraint and column

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

As Jens already pointed out, there is an issue with your ticks. First, the identifier quote character in MySQL is the backtick (`) by default, second, you are not using ticks for the table name in your foreign key constraint.

Replace all ticks with backticks and your statement will work (even without ticks around the table name in the foreign key constraint). Leave all ticks out and your statement will work. Change `REFERENCES Categorie` to `REFERENCES ‘Categorie’` and your statement will work (although probably not as expected).

I would recommend using backticks in all places as a good practice:

```
CREATE TABLE `Categorie` (
`catID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`naam` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`prioriteit` int(2) NOT NULL,
`subCatVan` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`catID`),
CONSTRAINT `subCatVan` FOREIGN KEY (`subCatVan`) REFERENCES `Categorie`

(`catID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

What currently happens is that you are actually not creating a table named `Categorie`, but instead a table named `‘Categorie’` (including the ticks). Because you are not using the same ticks in your foreign key constraint, MySQL looks for a table named `Categorie` without the ticks and thus cannot find the target for your reference.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE `Categorie` (
`catID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`naam` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`prioriteit` INT(2) NOT NULL,
`subCatVan` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`catID`),
CONSTRAINT `subCatVan` FOREIGN KEY (`subCatVan`) REFERENCES Categorie

(`catID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Could you explain, please?

Comment: @jens: Now i know why you ask me to explain.You put comment on given post. Answer is same as you add comment in post. I replaced all ticks with backticks in given post. sorry i didn't see the comment.

Comment: @NavjotSingh You should write your explanation in the answer so it is helpfull for all readers in the future.