# mysql add foreign key constraint referencing a view

Tags: mysql, view, foreign-keys, constraints

Can I add a foreign key constraint in MYSQL when the referenced table is actually a view?

Based on the following I might wonder that a table and a view are considered different formats https://stackoverflow.com/a/31183407/1342636

Seems to me this is not allowed, but I have not seen any which actually states it is disallowed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a field to be defined as a `foreign key`, the referenced parent field must have an index defined on it.

As per documentation on [**`foreign key` constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> REFERENCES parent_tbl_name (index_col_name,...)

As VIEWs are virtual tables, all its fields are also virtual.
And defining of `index` is not supported on *virtual* fields.

As per documentation on [**`Restrictions on Views`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-restrictions.html):

> It is not possible to create an index on a view.

And hence you can't use a virtual table, i.e. view, as a referenced parent table (which does not support indexes) to define and map a foreign key to create a child table.

**Example**:
[image]