# Laravel 4.2 many to many relation, use something else then the default ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I have 2 models and both they aren't using the ID from the table, but the field internal_id. So i customized my pivot schema but i got stuck on connecting them. Im getting the error:

```
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `seoshop_category_product` add constraint seoshop_category_product_category_id_foreign foreign key   
  (`category_id`) references `seoshop_categories` (`internal_id`) on delete cascade)
```

The code for the migration is:

```
Schema::create('seoshop_category_product', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('internal_id')->on('seoshop_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('internal_id')->on('seoshop_products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Both fields as seoshop_products.internal_id as seoshop_categories.internal_id are existing, column types are both int(11).

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

Migrations for the tables seoshop_categories and seoshop_products

```
//seoshop_products
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('seoshop_products', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('shop_id');
            $table->integer('internal_id')->signed()->index();
            $table->integer('internal_variant_id');
            $table->string('visible');
            $table->string('tags');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


//Table seoshop_categories
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('seoshop_categories', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('internal_id')->signed()->index();
            $table->datetime('seoshop_created_at');
            $table->datetime('seoshop_updated_at');
            $table->text('full_description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Okay so now i've create my table, and its working as how it should. I need to get my product with categories (many-2-many). So i use

```
SEOshopProduct::find(1)->with('categories')->get();
```

After a dd() the categories are empty and i've looked into my query how it is called:

```
[8] array(3) {
["query"] "select `seoshop_categories`.*, `seoshop_category_product`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `seoshop_category_product`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id` from `seoshop_categories` inner join `seoshop_category_product` on `seoshop_categories`.`id` = `seoshop_category_product`.`category_id` where `seoshop_category_product`.`product_id` in (?)"
["bindings"] array(1) {
[0] 8
}
["time"] 0.37
}
```

The internal_id's of both products and categories is greater then 10.000 and i dont see it back in the query.

My models:

Product:

```
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('SEOshopCategory', 'seoshop_category_product', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

Categories:

```
public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('SEOshopCategory', 'seoshop_category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To setup the foreign key constraint, the field definitions need to match exactly. In this case, however, the `seoshop_category_product.category_id` field is defined as an UNSIGNED INT, but the referenced `seoshop_categories.internal_id` field is defined as a SIGNED INT. The same is true for the foreign key for your products.

So, you can either update the `internal_id` fields on your categories and products tables to be unsigned, or you can update your foreign key fields on your pivot table to be signed.

Comment: Thanks Patricus, that makes sense. But how do i need to set up my new migration, or edit it?

Comment: Would added ->signed()->index(); be enough to my migrations for seoshop_products.internal_id and for the categories?

Comment: @DonnyvanV If you want to change your new pivot table to match your existing tables, just remove the call to `->unsigned()` on your category_id and product_id fields.

Comment: You can reference  [this link as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @patricus i tried to but that didnt worked out. Luckely for me that i just created the tables and they didnt had data

Comment: @patricus i've added my models, can you tell me why i don't get any results while both ID's are existing?

Comment: @DonnyvanV Please post this as a separate question. That will help future people who come searching for answers, and it will help you get more eyes on the issues you're facing.

Answer (score -1):

You can tell Laravel what the local and foreign keys are when you define the relationship in your model...

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'internal_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product', 'internal_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know that but its not with relating the model.php files, but drawing my table structure... Using a migration and then run artisan migrate gets me into trouble with the error above

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why you're trying to define these as foreign keys in your DB when Laravel provides you with a method to use alternate foreign keys out of the box within your model?

Comment: Isnt it a extra security detail to prevent it if something went really bad, and by then i mean really really bad :P