# #1005 - Can't create table on table one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, xampp, laravel-5

I have table products and table brands.I want to do one to many relationship. brand has many products.

This are tables with columns
[image]

And this sample of data in product
[image]
And this sample of data in brands
[image]
 I try to add foreign key .by this mysql statment

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT fk_brand_id FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brands(brand_id)
```

I get this error

```
 #1005 - Can't create table `larashop`.`#sql-dd4_77` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
```

Please anyone help me

Comment: Give us the table structures.

Comment: Please update with your data structures and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the storage engines on the tables match. For instance trying to set a FK between InnoDB and MyISAM will fail.

Edit answer.

you are unsigned datatype of brand_id from brands table & assign int datatype for foreign key brand_id in products table.try to change brand_id datatype of unsigned to integer in brands table.

please check this link
[MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: when I write SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM larashop it show all tables in larashop and engine is InnoDB.But when I write  SELECT products FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'larashop' AND engine = 'InnoDB';  I get error  #1054 - Unknown column 'products' in 'field list'

Comment: All tables in larashop in InnoDB engine

Comment: information_schema is not your database.A schema is a database, so the SCHEMATA table provides information about databases. information_schema also saved your trigger,procedure etc information.