# MySQL:ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database, spring, foreign-keys

I've been trying to follow a tutorial that I've came across, which is about spring security. In some place, I need to create 2 tables in my database which is `user` and `authorities`. While doing this, I am using this script that is suggested like in the tutorial. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html

I've already a `user` table in my db, so I just need to add `autohirites` table. Since I'm using **MySQL**, I've changed that query like below:

```
create table authorities (
      username varchar(70) not null,
      authority varchar(50) not null,
      CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references user(userFirstName));
      create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

Also, here is my user table too:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `userId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userFirstName` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `userLastName` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `userEmail` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    `userAddress` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `userPhoneNumber` INT(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `isActive` BINARY(50) NULL DEFAULT '1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0',
    `userPassword` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `userConfirmPassword` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

When I try to run my first query which is going to create authorities table, I am getting **ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint** error.

So far, I've been looked into these questions below, but none of them answered my problem + I think they are both the same questions:

[MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

[MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969060/mysql-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Are both tables set to InnoDB?

Comment: Make username  primary key in authorities table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making `userFirstName` column unique.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what the engine is for `authorities`, your user table does not have a unique index on userFirstName that would mean `authoritiest` would need to be INNODB. [because](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key.
>   This is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL.

But I don't recommend this at all, it's always best to have a foreign key referencing a PRIMARY KEY, where that's not possible another unique key.

What you should really do is change your table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE authorities (
      userid INT(11) not null,
      authority varchar(50) not null,
      CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references user(userid));
      create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority));
```

By doing so you are referencing a PRIMARY KEY but more importantly reducing a great deal of redundancy from your tables. There is absolutely no point in having the same ~70 character field repeated in both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. A similar answer was given 1 min ago before yours. But I'll consider your "using id instead of name" in my code. Thanks!

Comment: I could have made an answer well before that if I hadn't bothered to give an explaination :-)

Comment: ou shouldn't just consider that userId thing you should implement it because if you don't your databse isn't normalized.