# MYSQL: "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql

I try to create table that linked to two tables.
The linked table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cartsitems` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cart_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `price` DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `carts`(`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products`(`id`)
)
```

The products table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` INT,
  `description` VARCHAR(255),
  `price` DOUBLE(6,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `categories`(`id`)
)
```

The carts table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `carts` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `users_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users`(`id`)
 )
```

I search and I found this answer: [MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)
I check & I the engine is the same (cause I didnt set something else) , Also the collection 
The type is the same (both int)
And its uniqe (primary key)
What is the problem?

Comment: There's no `id` column in the `products` table.

Comment: In the `products` table, the foreign key should be `category_id`.

Comment: @Barmar , It's must be deleted on copy, I edited

Comment: What does `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` say after you get the error?

Comment: @Barmar , Thanks it's solved the problem

Comment: @Barmar: Do consider posting your suggested answer here as such so as it's marked as such.

Comment: @nyedidikeke I thought the question was about creating the `cartsitems` table. My comment applies to the `products` table.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing id field in products table.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_id` INT,
    `description` VARCHAR(255),
    `price` DOUBLE(6,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `categories`(`id`)
);
```