# Cannot add foreign key constraint, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: advocate, client and event. In event table, I have two fields that are referencing two fields from advocate table and one field referencing client, and when I try to add foreign key I get this cannot add foreign key constraint error.

```
create table advocate(

ida int(11) not null, 
idk int(11) not null,

#...

primary key(ida, idk)

)engine = InnoDB default charset=utf8;



create table client(

jmb varchar(13) not null primary key

#...

)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;



create table event(

ida int(11) not null,
idk int(11) not null,
jmb varchar(13) not null,

#...

primary key(ida,idk,jmb),

foreign key(ida, idk)
references advocate(ida, idk)
on update cascade
on delete restrict,

foreign key(jmb)
references client.jmb
on update cascade
on delete restrict


)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

Comment: whhat is the error?

Comment: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: If we are to help you, it's important to show the precise text of the command that fails and the precise text of the resulting error message. Please [edit] your question to provide those things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing:

```
foreign key(jmb)
references client.jmb
on update cascade
on delete restrict
```

to

```
foreign key(jmb)
references client (jmb)
on update cascade
on delete restrict
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you