# Flask-Migrate Alter Table Error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

i've been scratching my head for a bit of time now with this error and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Maybe you can help?

Using [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) i've modified my models and am attempting to migrate the database accordingly.

The error i'm running into seems to be between two specific models `User` and `Transaction`.

After running

```
$ python run.py db init
$ python run.py db migrate
$ python run.py db upgrade
```

I recieve this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1825, "Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'transaction_table'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'my_database/transaction_table_ibfk_1'") [SQL: 'ALTER TABLE transaction_table ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id)']
```

Here is how i've set up my models *note the **tablename** override*:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column('password', db.String(10))
    role = db.Column('role', db.String(3))
    registered_on = db.Column('registered_on', db.DateTime)
    transactions = db.relationship('transaction_table', backref=db.backref('user', lazy='joined'), lazy='dynamic')

class Transaction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transaction_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    transaction_date = db.Column('transaction_date', db.DateTime)
    requested_donor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('donor_db.id'))
```

I've used [this guide](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/) for setting up my models with Foreign Keys and relationships.

I've used this [Blog Post](https://techarena51.com/index.php/one-to-many-relationships-with-flask-sqlalchemy/) to help diagnose my problems to no avail. Might you know what i'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an error at the MySQL level, usually caused by inconsistent table settings across the two tables involved in the reference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint for ideas on how to troubleshoot.