# Problem with migration package and Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with a migration and package Teamwork (https://github.com/mpociot/teamwork)

I need an Emission to be able to have (N Teams), but when a migration is run, Laravel says

SQLSTATE [HY000]: General error: 1215 Unable to add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table emissions add constraint emissions_team_id_foreign foreign key ( team_id) references teams (id) on delete cascade)

I don't understand if it is something from the package or what may be happening.

The order of execution is first Teamwork and then the migration of Emission.

[image]

Comment: Searching for your error msg turns up many answers here on SO, do they help?  Also,  [please don't post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673142/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-laravel)

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes this is error

Comment: I found the problem:
If the PK is a BigInteger (20) not is possible make a relation with another table wich column id is a Integer(10).

Comment: Great - [that solution is right there in the duplicate I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55878646/6089612).  This question should be closed as a duplicate.