# Laravel Migration Error "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to run my migrations but keep getting the following error.

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `votes` add constraint `votes_topic_id_foreign` foreign key (`topic_id`) references `voting_topic_results` (`division_id`))
```

I have tried both solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673142/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-laravel/55878646) post with no joy.

My two migration files are:

voting_topic_results

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('voting_topic_results', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('division_id');
        $table->dateTime('date');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('aye_count');
        $table->integer('noe_count');
    });
}
```

votes

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('topic_id');
        $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('division_id')->on('voting_topic_results');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('user_aye_count')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_noe_count')->nullable();
        $table->unique(['topic_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}
```

EDIE***

I've updated my code to what the related question was referring to and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: If have have declared the relationships in your models, just avoid adding the foreign keys in the schema

Comment: The duplicate question gives you the exact answer. However, the canonical answer contsining all possible causes for this error messsge is in the following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457305/mysql-creating-tables-with-foreign-keys-giving-errno-150

Comment: In your `voting_topic_results` schemas, your `division_id` column isn't the same type as your declaration in `votes`.
`$table->integer('division_id')->unique();` is not equal to `$table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();` that's why the error occurs.
After correction, check that your `voting_topic_results` schemas migrate before `votes`.

Comment: @Atchiiii i've just removed the ```->unique()``` & ```->unsigned()``` and it's still giving the same error

Comment: @CIB verify that you are migrating the `voting_topic_results` schema before `votes`.

Comment: @Atchiiii yeah the ```voting_topic_results``` is run first