# MySQL can't apply foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make a database on phpmyadmin, but I have few problems to link my tables. Here are two of them.

First:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bati(
    code_bati CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    code_parcelle CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    surface_bati DOUBLE(15,2),
    ID_proprietaire CHAR(50),
    largeur DOUBLE(15,2),
    superficie DOUBLE(15,2),
    orientation CHAR(2),
    vocation VARCHAR(50),
    globalid VARCHAR(50),
    date_save DATE NOT NULL,
    date_last_mod DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_interne CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(code_bati, code_parcelle)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Second:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parcelle(
    fid_edi_parc INT UNSIGNED,
    code_lot CHAR(50),
    ID_parc CHAR(50),
    num SMALLINT(4),
    code_com CHAR(50),
    code_sec CHAR(50),
    code_sub_sec CHAR(50),
    figplan VARCHAR(50),
    code_apart VARCHAR(50),
    code_modif VARCHAR(50),
    code CHAR(50),
    code_parcelle CHAR(50),
    fid_perimetre_ppr DOUBLE(15,2),
    globalID CHAR(50),
    date_save DATE NOT NULL,
    date_last_mod DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_interne CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(code, code_parcelle)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Then I excecute this command to link them:

```
    ALTER TABLE bati
        ADD CONSTRAINT bati__code_parcelle__fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (code_parcelle) 
        REFERENCES parcelle(code_parcelle);
```

And I get this error:

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

I look for solutions on the internet (including this one [MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)), but I can not solve my problem, can you help me / explain why this error.

(sorry for my english, I'm french)

Comment: A foreign key relationship really only makes sense if you are referencing a full primary or unique key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index on the column being referenced, or at least it must appear in first position in a multi-column index.

From [the MySQL foreign keys documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

I think that the simplest solution here would be to change the order of the columns in the primary key of table `parcelle`, ie change:

```
PRIMARY KEY(code, code_parcelle)
```

To:

```
PRIMARY KEY(code_parcelle, code)
```

With this change, `code_parcelle` now appears in the first position in the composite index, which makes it possible to reference it as a foreign key.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5gww1KBDmqeef75puHVN2N/0)**.

NB: it would probably be a good idea to create a separate table to store the `code_parcelle`, and then refer to it from all other tables.