# error 1215 while trying to create foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create roles management system and I get error while trying to create mysql table with foreign keys. I checked w3school documents and everything seems to be same.

My error:

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE user_role (
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id)
);
```

I run this command:

> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

And got this:

Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.

Comment: You need to show us the `create table` statements for tables `users` and `roles`.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534977/mysql-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: @keidakida edited post

Comment: Aren't user_id and role_id composite primary keys in the user_role table? You haven't marked them as such.

Comment: Could you show the users and roles create table query? Could you also check the collation for your table and database are the same?