# How do I add a composite foreign key but still allow nulls in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, foreign-keys

I have two tables, `entity` and `entity_role`.  `entity` looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `entity` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`type`)
);
```

And `entity_role` looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `entity_role` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_entity_role_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `FK_entity_role_role_id` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_entity_role_role_id` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_entity_role_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
);
```

I'm trying to add a foreign key reference from `entity_role` to `entity` by running the following statement:

```sql
alter table entity_role add constraint `FK_entity_role_entity`
  foreign key(`entity_id`, `entity_type`)
  references `entity`(`id`, `type`)
  on delete cascade;
```

However I get back from the server:
[Code: 1005, SQL State: HY000]  (conn=26) Can't create table `entity_role` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

I've looked over this multiple times and read through the MariaDB documentation several times and I feel like I'm banging my head against the wall now.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Both tables are using the InnoDB engine.

Comment: your question title mentions null values but your question body does not.  do be aware that if any of the values in a composite foreign key are null, the non-null values may have any value, even ones not present in the foreign table.  https://dbfiddle.uk/kpRGR57a

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535110/742504) was exactly what I was looking for.  Specifically, MariaDB won't tell you why it doesn't like your foreign key unless you go ask the specific engine:

```sql
SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS;
```

Won't post the wall of text, but this line in particular was the relevant bit (and helpfully was at the very top!):

```
2023-05-19 14:39:14 0x7fc78c15e640 Error in foreign key constraint of table `default`.`entity_role`:
Alter  table `default`.`entity_role` with foreign key `FK_entity_role_entity` constraint failed. Field type or character set for column 'entity_type' does not match referenced column 'type'.------------
```

I had omitted omitted this in the question, not realizing that they were relevant, but the varchar columns all have `ascii_bin` collation.  All of them, that is, *except* for the `entity_type` column on `entity_role`, which had none set at all (I presume this means use the table default)!  Modifying the column to use a matching collation solved the problem.

Comment: If you found the answer already on SO, then why didn't you simply delete the question?