# Import mySQL data - wrong charset

Tags: php, mysql

I migrate to another ISP with my website and I have problem. I ake dump my mySQL database, import in new ISP and when connect from web I have bad signs like: "wy??�?czy?? si�? podczas u??ywania, nie uruchamia si�?,"

I'm from Poland so I use local signs like ę, ą etc. I don't know where is the problem with charset, I don't change this in database. How I can convert this database or another resolve this problem?

```
function db_connect(){
$connect_support = mysql_connect(SQL_SERVER, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS)
    or die('bd server');
mysql_select_db(SQL_DB)
    or die('table');
//$charset = mysql_client_encoding($connect_support);
//echo "Charset is: $charset\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up solving my problem:

First mysqldump -uusername -ppassword --default-character-set=latin1 database -r dump.sql

Then run this script

```
$search = array('/latin1/');
$replace = array('utf8');
foreach (range(128, 255) as $dec) {
$search[] = "/\x".dechex($dec)."/";
$replace[] = "&#$dec;";
}

 $input = fopen('dump.sql', 'r');
 $output = fopen('result.sql', 'w');

while (!feof($input)) {
 $line = fgets($input);
 $line = preg_replace($search, $replace, $line);
 fwrite($output, $line);
 }

fclose($input);
fclose($output);
```

Comment: Now, I have another charset and "wyÄ¹Â‚Ã„Â…czyÄ¹Â‚ siÃ„Â™ podczas uÄ¹Åºywania, nie uruchamia siÃ„Â™,"

Answer (score 0):

change collation

[change-collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294117/how-to-change-collation-of-database-table-column)

understand utf8 and have a look at:
[utf8-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

check the differences between the datatypes you can use.