# I Want to Change the Collation on my MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I recently upgraded my site to PHP 5.7 and a new install of the MySQL database. The previous data was imported.

Now I have a lot of the question marks in diamonds in outputted text. I have read up, and the problem seems to be that the collation of my database is set to latin1_swedish_ci and I need to be utf8 to correctly render special characters stored in the database.

If I change the collation will this potentially solve my problem, fixing the older postings?

Do I switch off the site before changing the collation, and does it require a reboot to take effect? I'm a little nervous about corrupting the data as my users would be extremely upset to lose their historical postings.

I am not setting up a new database, I've upgraded an existing database, and need to keep the historical data.

I followed one of the answers posted below and it worked for data that was inputted into the database before the upgrade, but now renders newer data with various â€œ in place of apostrophes, etc.

Comment: *"Now I have a lot of the question marks in diamonds in outputted text."* - so check the file's encoding, and if that still doesn't work, pass UTF-8 before querying

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: if you're worried about corrupting data, just copy that db in a tmp table

Comment: You can also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294117/how-to-change-collation-of-database-table-column

Comment: Thank you - the solution was very simple after all!  I used mysql_query('SET NAMEs utf8') and that solved the historical issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that does fix the historical posts, but breaks the newer posts (since the upgrade). I'm looking for a fix that will work for the historical data as well as the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST","DB_USER","PASSWORD","DB_NAME");
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

OR

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: But do not mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`; use only the latter.