# Query not working in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am having serious headache with MySQL database. Here is my problem.

I am developing a website in Php with SQL Server as database, everything working fine. **database 1**

Than I have to change database to MySQL, I've done that and create some stored procedures and function, everything working fine here too. **database 2**

Now I've have to shift MySQL database to another MySQL server, **database 3**. Problem occurs here because now my old stored procedure and query which I've created are not working. My **DB3** structure is same as **DB2**.

If I fire this query in **DB2** `select * from Online_Patient;` no error.

Same query in **DB3** throws an error:

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'Online_Patient' doesn't exist

But when I change my query to `select * from online_patient;` it gives me correct result.

So is there any way to solve this error or do I have to change all query and stored procedures, there are dynamic query in stored procedure so just can't convert upper case to lower case.

Comment: Check the collation of your database. Set it to case-insensitive. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294117/how-to-change-collation-of-database-table-column) might help.

Comment: i am using MySQL workbench , so can you guide me how to that?

Comment: I would suggest to rename the table in lowercase. Its a best practice to use table name in lowercase.

Comment: Did your mysql server run in Windows or Unix or Linux?

Comment: @Reno it's in windows

Comment: Please describe the way you migrated from db2 to db3.

Comment: @PavelPetrov through MySQL workbench migration tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate your mysql configuration file. It should be named **my.cnf**. You can run `mysqld --help --verbose` in the beginning of the output the are the default locations where you can look for the file. My output is:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf
```

Find the lower_case_table_names directive and set it to 1:

`lower_case_table_names = 1`

From MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

> If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases. For additional information, see Section 10.2.2, “Identifier Case Sensitivity”.

Then restart mysql server.

Comment: also this article might help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: my DB is on server so how can i change my.cnf ? serve will not let me change my.cnf file don't you think? if it possible please share.

Comment: If you have access to the server and rights to change the conf file it won't be problem. If you don't have access you should either rename all your tables or change your queries. I don't see other solution.