# WPGlobus not working for Arabic language in menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, translation

I am using the free version of `WPGlobus(1.9.15)` now I upgrade it to (1.9.24). First I work on localhost, its working perfectly on five languages `(English, Spanish, French, German, Arabic)` in menu, in content … means every where Then I upload it to the online server it also working perfectly on `(English, Spanish, French, German)` but not on `Arabic`.

The issue is when I translate a word `(English to Arabic)` in google translate and then paste Arabic word into menu its paste correctly like this

[image]

But when I saved it, the Arabic language only turned into these characters like this

[image]

You can see that only the Arabic language turned into this and its not working on my online server but its working perfectly in my localhost. I upgrade all plugins on the online server as well as in localhost. But the error comes only on the online server.

I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the database tables collations types to `utf8_general_ci` and also table fields collations change to `utf8_general_ci`.

You can do it by using `ALTER` command as:

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE column_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Or put this line in `config.php`

```
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
```

You can use `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8` or any other supported collation algorithm. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: If the above solution does not work then see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294117/how-to-change-collation-of-database-table-column

Comment: Changing the mysql charset to UTF8 makes a lot of sense. however I would recommend to go to `utf8mb4`, since mysql's `utf8` only covers a subset of UTF8. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, Thanks for the suggestion :)