# How to convert all tables in database to one collation?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting error:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='"

I tried changing both tables manually to `utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT` but I'm still getting the error.

Is there a way to convert all tables to `utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT` and be done with it?

Comment: Found this (had some good answers):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105572/a-script-to-change-all-tables-and-fields-to-the-utf-8-bin-collation-in-mysql

Comment: [Click here for script and follow the steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37049697/5737771)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You need to execute a alter table statement for each table. The statement would follow this form:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
[[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
[COLLATE collation_name]
```

Now to get all the tables in the database you would need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="YourDataBaseName"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

So now let MySQL write the code for you:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME," COLLATE your_collation_name_here;") AS    ExecuteTheString
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="YourDatabaseName"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

You can copy the results and execute them. I have not tested the syntax but you should be able to figure out the rest. Think of it as a little exercise.

Comment: For someone looking for a quick perfect solution, I used the following to work with table names being possible keywords and of course using semicolons :) 
`CONCAT("ALTER TABLE \`", TABLE_NAME,"\` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;")`

Comment: I wrapped this query with `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ExecuteTheString SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM (....) t` So that I could grab all the tables at once more easily in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: This return an empty result in MySQL PHPMYAdmin

Comment: @Michael still works for me. Did you change the parameters to reflect your situation?

Comment: @Namphibian nope i only replace the schema with my own schema and table type (InnoDB)

Comment: @Michael there is no table type: InnoDB. InnoDB is a storage engine it is not a table type. The valid values for table type are system view, base table , view.  If you are using InnoDB as value then the query is performing correctly/.

Comment: @Micheal hint: you can search for engine InnoDB.

Comment: @Namphibian this is ridiculous to me, when i was searching for what is the mean by table table, i am seeing type of storage engine that got me confuses, okay can u give me an illustration of table type please.

Comment: Or should i just write BASE TABLE, there

Comment: @Michael Yes, actually write "BASE TABLE".  That means it's not a View and not a System Table

Comment: This idea is so great. It helped me a lot. Simply to generate one script that will be executed separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 83):

Better option to change also collation of varchar columns inside table also

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME,'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') AS    mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= "myschema"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

Additionnaly if you have data with forein key on non utf8 column before launch the bunch script use

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

It means global SQL will be for mySQL :

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE `table1` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `table2` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `tableXXX` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

But take care if according mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-column.html,

> If you use ALTER TABLE to convert a column from one character set to another, MySQL attempts to map the data values, but if the character sets are incompatible, there may be data loss. "

EDIT: Specially with column type enum, it just crash completly enums set (even if there is no special caracters)
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26731

Comment: After trying many solutions this is by far the best answer and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 37):

@Namphibian's suggestion helped me a lot...
went a little further though and added columns and views to the script

just enter your schema's name below and it will do the rest

```
-- set your table name here
SET @MY_SCHEMA = "";

-- tables
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_NAME," CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;") as queries
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@MY_SCHEMA
  AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"

UNION

-- table columns
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", C.TABLE_NAME, " CHANGE ", C.COLUMN_NAME, " ", C.COLUMN_NAME, " ", C.COLUMN_TYPE, " CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;") as queries
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as C
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as T
        ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.COLLATION_NAME is not null
    AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA=@MY_SCHEMA
    AND T.TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"

UNION

-- views
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ", V.TABLE_NAME, " AS ", V.VIEW_DEFINITION, ";") as queries
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS as V
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as T
        ON V.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
WHERE V.TABLE_SCHEMA=@MY_SCHEMA
    AND T.TABLE_TYPE="VIEW";
```

Comment: I used your code to success, thank you. I would recommend to add foreign key check enable/disable and also add quotes around the table keys.

Comment: It is not necessary to do the columns individually as `ALTER TABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` automatically converts all columns

Comment: Works great. In my case I had to quote table/column names to avoid keyword conflicts (such as `Desc`, `Password`..) to success.

Answer (score 28):

If you're using PhpMyAdmin, you can now:

1. Select the database.
2. Click the "Operations" tab.
3. Under "Collation" section, select the desired collation.
4. Click the "Change all tables collations" checkbox.
5. A new "Change all tables columns collations" checkbox will appear.
6. Click the "Change all tables columns collations" checkbox.
7. Click the "Go" button.

I had over 250 tables to convert. It took a little over 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 21):

Below is the more accurate query.
I am giving example how to convert it to utf8

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_NAME,"` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;") AS    mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="myschema"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

Comment: Good, but I needed to change it to `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` for tables with data

Answer (score 9):

You can use this BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="YOUR_DATABASE_USER"
PASSWORD="YOUR_USER_PASSWORD"
DB_NAME="DATABASE_NAME"
CHARACTER_SET="utf8" # your default character set
COLLATE="utf8_general_ci" # your default collation

tables=`mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e "SELECT tbl.TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES tbl WHERE tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA = '$DB_NAME' AND tbl.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'"`

for tableName in $tables; do
    if [[ "$tableName" != "TABLE_NAME" ]] ; then
        mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e "ALTER TABLE $DB_NAME.$tableName DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $CHARACTER_SET COLLATE $COLLATE;"
        echo "$tableName - done"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 7):

For phpMyAdmin I figured this out:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME," CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;" SEPARATOR ' ') AS    OneSQLString
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="yourtableschemaname"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

Just change yourtableschemaname and you're fine.

Comment: @LucaC. you need to increase group_concat limit ex: `set session group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;`

Answer (score 4):

Taking the answer from @Petr Stastny a step further by adding a password variable.  I'd prefer if it actually took it in like a regular password rather than as an argument, but it's working for what I needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# mycollate.sh <database> <password> [<charset> <collation>]
# changes MySQL/MariaDB charset and collation for one database - all tables and
# all columns in all tables

DB="$1"
PW="$2"
CHARSET="$3"
COLL="$4"

[ -n "$DB" ] || exit 1
[ -n "$PW" ]
[ -n "$CHARSET" ] || CHARSET="utf8mb4"
[ -n "$COLL" ] || COLL="utf8mb4_bin"

PW="--password=""$PW"

echo $DB
echo "ALTER DATABASE $DB CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql -u root "$PW"

echo "USE $DB; SHOW TABLES;" | mysql -s "$PW" | (
    while read TABLE; do
        echo $DB.$TABLE
        echo "ALTER TABLE $TABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql "$PW" $DB
    done
)

PW="pleaseEmptyMeNow"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my version of a bash script. It takes database name as a parameter and converts all tables to another charset and collation (given by another parameters or default value defined in the script).

```
#!/bin/bash

# mycollate.sh <database> [<charset> <collation>]
# changes MySQL/MariaDB charset and collation for one database - all tables and
# all columns in all tables

DB="$1"
CHARSET="$2"
COLL="$3"

[ -n "$DB" ] || exit 1
[ -n "$CHARSET" ] || CHARSET="utf8mb4"
[ -n "$COLL" ] || COLL="utf8mb4_general_ci"

echo $DB
echo "ALTER DATABASE $DB CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql

echo "USE $DB; SHOW TABLES;" | mysql -s | (
    while read TABLE; do
        echo $DB.$TABLE
        echo "ALTER TABLE $TABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql $DB
    done
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a copy-paste bash script:

```
var=$(mysql -e 'SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_NAME," CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci;") AS execTabs FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="zabbix" AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"' -uroot -p )

var+='ALTER DATABASE zabbix CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'

echo $var | cut -d " " -f2- | mysql -uroot -p zabbix
```

Change zabbix to your database name.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from G H I've added the user and host parameters incase you need to do this on a remote server

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # mycollate.sh <database> <user> <password> [<host> <charset> <collation>]
    # changes MySQL/MariaDB charset and collation for one database - all tables and
    # all columns in all tables

    DB="$1"
    USER="$2"
    PW="$3"
    HOST="$4"
    CHARSET="$5"
    COLL="$6"

    [ -n "$DB" ] || exit 1
    [ -n "$USER" ] || exit 1
    [ -n "$PW" ] || exit 1
    [ -n "$HOST" ] || HOST="localhost"
    [ -n "$CHARSET" ] || CHARSET="utf8mb4"
    [ -n "$COLL" ] || COLL="utf8mb4_general_ci"

    PW="--password=""$PW"
    HOST="--host=""$HOST"
    USER="--user=""$USER"

    echo $DB
    echo "ALTER DATABASE $DB CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql "$HOST" "$USER" "$PW"

    echo "USE $DB; SHOW TABLES;" | mysql  "$HOST" "$USER" "$PW" | (
        while read TABLE; do
            echo $DB.$TABLE
            echo "ALTER TABLE $TABLE CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET $CHARSET COLLATE $COLL;" | mysql  "$HOST" "$USER" "$PW" $DB
        done
    )

    PW="pleaseEmptyMeNow"
```

Answer (score 0):

***I will share my answer using MySQL procedure.
You need to run 3 sql command.***

### 1.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateTable;
```

### 2.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTable()
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE _table_name CHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
            WHERE table_schema = 'my_db_name' AND table_type = "BASE TABLE";
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;
    My_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO _table_name;
        SET @my_table_name = _table_name;

        IF done THEN
          LEAVE My_loop;
        END IF;

        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

        SET @stmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', @my_table_name, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;'); 
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stmt; 
        EXECUTE stmt1; 
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;   
        
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
            
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### 3.

```
CALL UpdateTable();
```

Then run first one again. If you don't want to store the procedure.