# How can I search and replace a string from an undetermined number of columns and tables using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Using purely MySQL, I want to search and replace 'oldString' with 'newString' from and undetermined number of tables and columns.  A search for my table prefix in information_schema, reveals all the tables that I need to look for.

I have the following trials:
Querying DB table prefix on information_schema

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_name LIKE  '%mysite_www%'
```

Results:

```
+-----------------+----------------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA    | TABLE_NAME                 |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
| myDB            | mysite_www_moredata        |
| myDB            | mysite_www_data            |
| myDB            | mysite_www_urls            |
| myDB            | mysite_www_pages           |
| myDB            | mysite_www_feedback        |
| myDB            | mysite_www_comments        |
| myDB            | mysite_www_links           |
+-----------------+----------------------------+
Query results yields about 200 tables or so.
```

I want to take the results, filter it for a particular string and replace it with a new one. Replace 'oldString' with 'newString'.

For each TABLE_NAME, search for any column WHERE column LIKE '%oldString%'.

```
WHERE CONCAT(table1, table2, ... tableN) LIKE 'oldString';
```

For each column result, update 'oldString' to 'newString'.

```
UPDATE tableN SET columnN = REPLACE (columnN, '%oldString%', 'newString') WHERE URL LIKE '%oldString%';
```

I need to do this in pure MySQL as it will be a store procedure.  Any assistance or tips is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by using information_Schema you can query both the tables and columns to get a result. I have done something similar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859966/how-to-convert-all-tables-in-database-to-one-collation) SO answer.

Essentially query the information_schema and let MySQL construct the SQL for you. The above link should get you going.

UPDATE:

You can use the following query to construct all the Update statements

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ',TABLENAME, 'SET ', COLUMN_NAME,'= REPLACE (',COLUMN_NAME, '''%oldString%'', ''newString'') WHERE URL LIKE ''%oldString%''')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE  '%somecriteria%' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%somecriteria%'
```

Insert these resulting string into a temp table then loop through the rows executing the string by using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Thank you, sorting through the information_Schema was part of the answer.